# How do have a shared docker volume that also links to host folder

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-volume

I've been trying to follow a docker tutorial to use nginx as proxy in front of my app.

Previously I've used definitions that map my app's `static` folder from my source into my container, e.g.

```
   volumes:
     - ./project/static/:/home/app/web/static
```

Now the nginx setup splits my services into the web app and the ngnix:

```
services:

  web:
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
    ...


  nginx:
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/static
    ...

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

Is there a way to make `static_volume` behave like the first example, linked to my local folder?

Or is there a good way to copy my local static files into the volume on building?

Comment: You can copy the static files into the _image_.  In particular, you can build a custom image `FROM nginx`, and `COPY` the static assets into that image too.  I would not recommend using volumes or bind mounts here.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, I see, just copy and serve from within nginx without any proxying for those static files specifically. Why would volumes/bind mounts not be advisable?

Comment: That named volumes work at all is very Docker-specific, and their contents don't update if the image updates (you could be serving old versions of static assets with a named-volume setup).  Bind mounts require you to have the source code checked out to run the application, where you'd typically prefer your Docker images to be self-contained.